# C++ blocking input

Tags: c++, multithreading, c++11, input, c++17

Hello guys I created a Hangman game in C++, which runs on 2 threads - input thread, which processes what char did user typed and output thread which handles if user win or lose. However, I encountered a little problem with the input thread. When i get to the cin >> in input thread and the output thread evaluates that user won/lost, its still waiting for the input from user and after user typed something game finally ends. I would be happy for every idea. Thank you all guys.

```
    void update() {
        if (timeLeft == 0 || wrongTries == 10) {
            lost = true;
            gameEnded = true;
        } else if (win) {
            win = true;
            gameEnded = true;
        }

    }

   void inputThread() {
      while (true) {
            if (gameEnded) {
                system("clear");
                break;
            }

            cin >> input;
            if (input == '0') {
                system("clear");
                ended = true;
                break;
            }

         // following code ...

        }
        cv.notify_all();
    }

    void outputThread() {

        while (true) {
            if (input == '0' || gameEnded) {
                system("clear");
                break;
            }
            
            // following code ...

                update();
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: *What* non-blocking input? This input is blocking.

Comment: yes and i want to make this input non-blocking xd